# Xcode4 Automatic Generation of @property declarations and all that goes with it

Tags: xcode, code-generation, properties, xcode4

When I was using Xcode 3 I had configured it with a perl script I found on the web that allowed me to automatically generate the @property, @synthesize and dealloc code for new instance variables. Xcode 4 doesn't have that User Scripts menu though.

Is there a way to plug in these kinds of User Scripts for Xcode 4 or does Xcode 4 have a new feature that generates that stuff automatically? (I've looked and can't find one though).

I'm not talking about linking to IBOutlets. I know that I can drag from a xib and it will create all of the right stuff for IBOutlets, but I'm looking for something that will create @property, @synthesize and dealloc code for any instance variable.

Thanks,
Kenny

Comment: I don't have a solution for you but I've heard it suggested that the services menu might be the way to get this kind of scripting in Xcode 4.  For the daring: there seem to be some (undocumented?) plugin interfaces for Xcode...

Answer (score 3):

I would strongly (and I can't emphasize this enough) suggest the application:

[Accessorizer](http://www.kevincallahan.org/software/accessorizer.html)

This is by far the most useful application for writing objective-C and objective-C 2.0 code that I have found. Originally written in the pre ObjC2.0 days, it created ivar getters and setters for you. Over the years it just keeps evolving. Now it does properties, container classes, key value encoding, KVO.

It tailors to your style: What line do you put brackets on, how do you indent, how do you comment? It also installs as a service so you can call it up from XCode, copy to the clipboard and paste right back into XCode.

I am not the author, I get nothing for plugging this. However, I have introduced its usage to every Mac team I've worked on and have converted every Obj-C programmer to it on first use.

It's got a demo period. Definitely at least try it out and see if it solves your issue.

Comment: This seems like an ~ok~ way to go about it, but for $10 I would expect something that is a LOT more magic. I've been previously using the perl+applescript found at http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/12/instance-variable-to-synthesized.html That's the level of automation I'm looking for. I don't have to hit a massive key combo, then navigate, then key combo, then navigate, then key combo, then navigate, then key combo.  The perl script was just one key combo and EVERYTHING was done automatically. :/ I'll vote you up, but this isn't the answer I'm looking for. :(

Comment: Not as neat as the Matt Gallagher script option in xCode 3, but using Accessorizer with xCode 4 seems to do the job for me, would recommend looking at it.  Just wish you didn't have to jump into the implementation file to do the inserts.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get the Xcode 3 perl script mentioned above working under Xcode 4 as a behaviour.

I put it up on github. https://bitly.com/HXHiij

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested either of these yet, but both claim to support Xcode 4:

1. https://github.com/CraigWilliams/property_synthesize_dealloc
2. https://public.me.com/dhoerl (Navigate to Xcode/PropertyMaster)

Comment: I've tried these Service-based solutions before with no luck, but I'll give it a try again and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I also miss the property related scripts, but I have found a workaround.  As noted elsewhere, XCode 4 will automatically generate the property/synthesize/dealloc code for IBoutlets that are hooked up through IB.

So I have a dummy XIB in my project called Property_Hack.XIB with some UILabels, and whenever I need a new property for a class I go to Property_Hack, change the owner, and "connect" a label to the file.  All you have to do is enter the name of the ivar you want, and XCode will add the @property statement to the .h, and in the .m it will add the @synthesize and dealloc code.  Then I modify the .h (delete IBoutlet keyword, and change UILabel to the datatype you want).

Rather hackish and far from perfect, but it is still a time saver compared to the manual effort of modifying both files.   Since NSIntegers and BOOLs do not need dealloc code, and are assign instead of retain, I usually set them up manually instead of using this approach.  Whether or not NSStrings should be copy or retain is an argument I will not rehash here :-)

Comment: Severely limited and convoluted to get anything other than UI elements isn't really a solution. Every modern IDE in the world has a way to automatically generate your getters and setters.

Comment: I don't disagree Kenny, I think this is a major oversight and makes me grit my teeth.  For any serious app development, however, anything that speeds up the workflow is better than nothing.  The enterprise iPad app I am working on has 67 classes with 503 properties.  :)